# Unable to add "WindowsAzure.Storage" dependency to .Net Core (ASP.NET 5) class library

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sdk-.net

My project solution is set up this way contains the following projects

```
MyProjectSolution.sln
    MyProject.WebPI(Asp.net 5 WebAPI)
    MyProject.Data(Asp.net 5 class libray)
    MyProject.Domain(Asp.net 5 class libray)
```

I followed the steps listed in the articles below
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-connected-services-storage/ and https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-blobs/ 
which changed my project.json to include this dependency  **"WindowsAzure.Storage": "4.3.2-preview"**

but then resulted in an error stating WindowsAzure.Storage is not supported on DNXCoreVersion=5.0

Note:
1) Also I tried adding the above dependency manually to check if it resulted in the same or a different error - no change.

2) I tried browsing to the location of the sdks %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\\ref\ but could not find it. Attached is the screen shot of the dlls I found.

Is there a specific version I can try? or Am i missing something important here?

Thanks!
[image]

```js
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "MyProject.Data Class Library",
  "authors": [""],
  "tags": [""],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      /*These were added after I connected to the Azure Storage as seen in the article that did  NOT exist before*/
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.Data.Edm": "5.6.3",
        "Microsoft.Data.OData": "5.6.3",
        "Microsoft.Data.Services.Client": "5.6.3",
        "System.Spatial": "5.6.3"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.IO": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "MyProject.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    /*This was added after I connected to the Azure Storage as seen in the article that did not exist before*/
    "WindowsAzure.Storage": "4.3.2-preview",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use 7.0.2-preview

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/7.0.2-preview

According to the changelog, it is updated to use the RC2 release of .Net Core 1.0.

7.1.1-preview was updated for the RTM release of .Net Core 1.0 but currently does not seem to be available via NuGet. (NuGet [page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/7.1.1-preview) says "The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore.")

Also, note that this contains a dependencies on ODataLib packages for which there currently is no .Net Core version. See [this note for WindowsAzure.Storage readme](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/README.md#odata) which states:

> The ODataLib packages currently do not support "netstandard1.6" or "netcoreapp1.0" frameworks in projects depending on the current relase of Dotnet CoreCLR. Thus, you may encounter failures while trying to restore the ODataLib dependencies for one of the targeted frameworks mentioned above. Until the support is added, if you run into this, you can use the imports statement within the framework node of your project.json file to specify to NuGet that it can restore the packages targeting the framework within the "imports" statement as shown below:
>
> ```
>    "imports": [
>      "dnxcore50",
>      "portable-net451+win8"
>    ]
> ```

**EDIT:** Use WindowsAzure.Storage 7.1.3-preview

Comment: Thanks for this, and for the update to keep the answer current.  Are there any potential issues with adding the additional import in (portable-net451+win8)?  I am deploying to the Azure App Service, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @cbailiss: It's worked for me on Windows. I've had problems running on Mac which I suspect is related to this.

Comment: @Alex: "imports" is basically saying: I know it isn't made for this framework but use it anyway. So if you're using this on any other platform than 'portable-net451/win8', you'll run into issues. Since there aren't any ports yet of Spatial and OData (at the time of writing) this won't work on Mac yet.

A workaround is creating an HTTP client and calling the API via HTTP directly.

Comment: @Jeroen - good point and thanks for the clarification. I had suspected as such as it would not work  on my Mac. Personally, I am going to wait a bit and hope for the dependencies to catch up before working extensively with .NET core. I see WindowsAzure.Storage up to 7.2.1 so maybe it's time to retest.

Comment: 8.0.1 is the current version

Answer (score -1):

This is because the **Windows Azure Storage 4.3.2-preview** nuget is a very old release which published on November 2014, which does not compatible with the current ASP.NET Core.

http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/4.3.2-preview

You could refer to the Release Notes of the Windows Azure Storage nuget package below to get the version/revision which compatible with the target ASP.NET Core that you're using.

[Release Notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, I was nt clear - the version of dll is or was not my choice. It was this version that got added automatically when I tried connecting to an Azure storage account. I tried other verions as well none of which that had supported for DNXCore=Version 5.0

Comment: Yes I am able to update. Would having my project.json here help?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the latest ASP.NET core files and config structure since it has major breaking changes, can't advice on this.